# Windows Rhapsody c++ project - Failed to connect to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, rhapsody

We are just starting out with Rhapsody 8.2.1 and we are trying to link it to VisualStudio 2012 and windows 7.

On my PC I have MSVS 2012 and 2013.

I have checked various answers out there which got me to fix / check:

- I have setup MSVS 2012 with the Rhapsody add-in and I can see it in the add-in manager.
- I have setup my visual studio configuration in Rhapsody, with the correct IDEVersion (v11).
- I have not got any Windows UAC settings blocking.
- We have tried to uninstall / Re-install Rhapsody.

I can generate the code files, but when I try to run make I get the error: "Failed to connect to Visual Studio". I have not found any solutions to this yet - any pointers appreciated.

**note:** VisualStudio 2012 application does open - but its blank (no project / files are open).

Answer (score 0):

do you see Rhapsody addin path in VS Tools/Options/Add-in/Macros Security list? It should include something like **\VisualStudio\VisualStudio2012** value.

Regards,Vladimir

Comment: "`I have setup MSVS 2012 with the Rhapsody add-in and I can see it in the add-in manager.`" - yes : )

Answer (score 0):

did you check Rhapsody box in Tools->Add-Ins manager window?
Another question: which CPP_CG.MSVC.IDEVersion property value is set in your Rhapsody VisualStudio configuration? Its default value is VC10 and Rhapsody will look for VS 2010, if you didn't change it to VC11.

Regards,
Vladimir

Comment: Seriously dude...I have answered all this in my question : )

Comment: Ok,ok. Sometimes people write one thing but do different thing. I think you have no choice but ask IBM Support for help. Regards,V.